# Interface inheritance/hierarchies in .Net - is there a better way?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I figure I'll use a case study of something in my code as an example of what I mean.

Right now, I'm working on a behavior/action system for my component-based game system. GameObjects can have an IBehaviorComponent and an IActionComponent attached to them, which, showing only the relevant details, expose the following:

```
public interface IBehaviorComponent : IBaseComponent
{
   IBehavior Behavior { get; }
}

public interface IActionComponent : IBaseComponent
{
   IAction Action { get; }
   void ExecuteAction(IGameObject target = null);
}
```

Now, this is all fine so far (at least to me!). But, trouble begins to brew when I look at implementations of IActionComponent.

For example, a simple IActionComponent implementation:

```
public class SimpleActionComponent : IActionComponent
{
   public IAction Action { get; protected set; }

   public void ExecuteAction(IGameObject target = null)
   {
      Action.Execute(target);
   }

   public void Update(float deltaTime) { } //from IBaseComponent
}
```

But, let's say I want to introduce a more complex IActionComponent implementation that allows for actions to be executed on a timed schedule:

```
public class TimedActionComponent : IActionComponent
{
   public IAction Action { get; protected set; }

   public float IdleTime { get; set; }

   public float IdleTimeRemaining { get; protected set; }

   public void ExecuteAction(IGameObject target = null)
   {
      IdleTimeRemaining = IdleTime;
   }

   public void Update(float deltaTime)
   {
      if (IdleTimeRemaining > 0f)
      {
         IdleTimeRemaining -= deltaTime;
      }
      else
      {
         Action.Execute(target);
      }
   }
}
```

And now, let's say I want to expose IdleTime so that it can be changed by outside influences. My thoughts at first were to create a new interface:

```
public interface ITimedActionComponent : IActionComponent
{
   float IdleTime { get; set; }

   float IdleTimeRemaining { get; set; }
}
```

However, the issue here is that my component system stores everything at one-level-up from IBaseComponent. So, the action component for a GameObject is retrieved as an IActionComponent, -not- as, say, an ITimedActionComponent, or an IRandomizedActionComponent, or even an ICrashTheProgramActionComponent. I hope the reasons for this are obvious, as I want anything to be able to query the GameObject for one of it's components without having to know exactly what it wants beyond the basic type of component (IActionComponent, IRenderableComponent, IPhysicsComponent, etc.)

Is there a cleaner way of handling this, that will allow me to expose these properties defined in child classes without everything having to cast the retrieved IActionComponent to the type it's interested in? Or is that simply the only/best way of accomplishing this. Something like:

```
public void IWantYouToAttackSuperSlow(IGameObject target)
{
   //Let's get the action component for the gameobject and test if it's an ITimedActionComponent...
   ITimedActionComponent actionComponent = target.GetComponent<IActionComponent>() as ITimedActionComponent;

   if (actionComponent != null) //We're okay!
   {
      actionComponent.IdleTime = int.MaxValue; //Mwhaha
   }
}
```

Right now I am thinking that's *The Only Way*, but I figured I'd see if there's a pattern hiding in the woodwork that I'm ignorant of, or if anyone can suggest a much better way of accomplishing this to begin with.

Thanks!

Comment: My other thought was to use another object inside, such as IActionComponentExecutor, which would decide when to call Action.Execute(), but I think that brings me back to square one in a round-a-bout fashion - external objects will then have to track down IActionComponentTimedExecutor (oh~ we're gettin' enterprise-y now!) to change IdleTime.

Comment: Out of interest - is the state for actionComponent.IdleTime stored in some kind of generic bag?  If so you can have `Apply(BagData bag)` and `Store(BagData bag)` methods on your base interface.  That said, you might also need to consider some metadata-type system that you can use to query properties wihtou needing to know the derived types.  `TypeDescriptor` is a ready-rolled starting point that is used by things like property grids etc.

Comment: No, it currently isn't. I'm not entirely familiar with the concept either - is there a reference you could perhaps provide?

Comment: Well, really, just think of it as being like serialization I guess.  But it might not be appropriate if you want to be able to write code like that that 'knows' about there being a value that can be set by virtue of the fact that it knows about the derived interface.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I think it may, perhaps, be a bit *too* general for this case though. Other code will know about the derived interfaces, I just needed a nice way to get that access.

Answer (score 1):

The code you showed that casts-down an `IActionComponent` to an `ITimedActionComponent` is (as far as I can see) unavoidable- you have to be aware of the `IdleTime` properties in order to use them, right?

I think the trick here would be to hide that not-so-nice-looking code where the classes that use your `IActionComponent` won't have to deal with it.
My first thought on how to do this is to use a `Factory`:

```
  public void IWantYouToAttackSuperSlow(IGameObject target)
{
   //Let's get the action component for the gameobject 
   IActionComponent actionComponent = ActionComponentsFactory.GetTimedActionComponentIfAvailable(int.MaxValue); 
}
```

and your factory's method:

```
public IActionComponent GetTimedActionComponentIfAvailable(IGameObject target, int idleTime)
{
var actionComponent = target.GetComponent<IActionComponent>() as ITimedActionComponent;

   if (actionComponent != null) //We're okay!
   {
      actionComponent.IdleTime = int.MaxValue; //Mwhaha
   }
return (actionComponent != null)? actionComponent : target.GetComponent<IActionComponent>();
}
```

Comment: In regards to your first sentence there - I do agree, and I can't see any real way around it. I suppose I was fishing/praying for some miracle architecture that would fix everything. But I guess we're just not quite there yet ;) As for the Factory method, I like that, and it will at least help clean things up a bit. I'm going to take a look at how well this will work with what I have right now.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, it's not a good idea to test for a specific implementation by casting to subtypes. From the examples you have provided it looks like you have an `IGameObject` that you want to perform some action on. Rather than having your `IActionComponent` expose a method that takes the `IGameObject` as an argument you could sort of do it the other way around, i.e. let the `IGameObject` take one, or many if you prefer, actions that you can execute.

```
interface IActionComponent
{
    ExecuteAction();
}

interface IGameObject
{
    IActionComponent ActionComponent { get; }
}
```

then in the executing method do

```
public void IWantYouToAttackSuperSlow(IGameObject target)
{
    target.ActionComponent.ExecuteAction();
}
```

Depending on how you implement IActionComponent, polymorphism will make sure that the right code is executed.

There is a pattern called [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) that seems to fit your need.

Comment: Ah, the case study I provided here was just one instance of this interface inheritance issue I'm running in to. As I'm developing a component-based system, IGameObject is *only* an extremely simple container for components, with absolutely no logic or knowledge about any "real" components. In essence, it's just a GUID that allows components that cover a given 'entity' to be tied to that 'entity' (but I have encapsulated that concept in an interface/class to provide for easy component retrieval).

Comment: @Icelight: I can't claim to understand your architecture fully. However, your sentence *"IGameObject is only an extremely simple container for components, with absolutely no logic.."* sounds strange to me. Whenever I hear of a class that 'should be only a bag of properties, without any logic', I'm reminded of the first thing I've learned about object-oriented programming: It's about putting the **behaviour** where the **data** is. So, in my opinion, logic-less classes are a bit of a code smell.

Comment: @sJhonny: I understand what you're getting at. However, in this case, a GameObject was put in place for my convenience, rather than need. In a "true" component based game system, all of the components would be floating around in the great big component cloud (or, more likely, sitting in managers dedicated to their component type), with only something like a GUID tying ones that belong to the same entity together. Rather than take this approach I'm using a GameObject which holds all components of the same entity - convenience, as this approach is easier to visualize for myself.